# Remove product thumbnail from specific product page in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Let's say I have 2 different products A & B. Both products have image, Now I want to remove image from product B how can I do this?

I was trying to use hook on product page but I do not know how to use correctly `is_product` function.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Tell us what you already tried and what is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using css

You can put your product id below

```
.postid-5065 div.images {
   display:none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy woocmmerce templates in you theme files and put hard code condition in Wocommerce->single-product->product-image.php file